# Automatically Check In File On Save In Visual Source Safe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, checkin

Is it possible to automatically check a file into Visual Source Safe after the local (working) copy had been changed?  Our current process involves editing our code on Windows computer that are running VSS Explorer and after a check in VSS shadow copies the files to the devel Linux server.  We're spending a lot of time manually checking the file back in through VSS and would like to just have it push every time we save the files.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think VSS supports automatic check-in.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write a small app that monitors the folder for updated files, and when they are updated, open your VSS connection and checkin to VSS via a specified or hardcoded path? Just an idea though. I believe you can use something such as FileSystemWatcher. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I was hoping for something that's already written.  :-)